# Compactness theorem question

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Well in my topology notes I have:

> $A \subset$ $\mathbb{R^n}$ is compact iff $A$ is closed and enclosed.

But it doesn't specify the topology, my question is if this is true for any topology or only with the usual topology of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: Is "enclosed" the same as "bounded"? Observe that it does't work if you are working with discrete topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true in the standard topology of $\mathbb R^n$ and in some other topologies, but **not true in all topologies**

For example, in the discrete metric, every set is closed and bounded, but only finite sets are compact. Therefore, any infinite set is closed, enclosed and non-compact.